# Java socket: how the server can reads multiple lines from the client

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I create chat app one to one by using Java programming language
I faced issue: client can't send a new message until he receives a message from the server.

Comment: Post your code here or down vote is comming

Comment: @mr.icetea you might want to ask the question in a different way.

Comment: This all depends on how you have coded both the client and server. Do you have one or multiple connections per client? Do you have one thread per send or one thread per client? Does the server receive in a thread pool or do you only have one thread accepting messages from all clients? Do you use blocking I/O etc.

Comment: The key insight is that each connection is like a full duplex pipe, but that each connection has a limited buffer. This means that the client cannot write for very long without the server reading. So if the client writes a second message while the server is busy handling the first message of the same connection, the client will block. The same goes if the server is busy handling a message from another connection. The easiest way of handling this is to use one thread per accepted connection on the server, preferrably by using a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a multithreaded application.
The client will run 2 threads:
1) Sender thread which will run on send button. You can every time create a new instance of this thread on clicking send button.
2) The receiver thread will keep on running continuously and check the stream for any message. Once it gets a message on stream it will write the same on console.

Will update you shortly with the code.
Thanks

Written this code long back similarly you can write server using other port

```
package com.clients;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ClientFullDuplex extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame jframe;
    private JPanel jp1, jp2;
    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JTextArea jta;
    private JTextField jtf;
    private JButton send;
    private Thread senderthread;
    private Thread recieverthread;
    private Socket ds;
    private boolean sendflag;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClientFullDuplex sfd = new ClientFullDuplex();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public ClientFullDuplex() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        initGUI();
        ds = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1124);
        initNetworking();
    }

    public void initGUI() {

        jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setTitle("Client");
        jframe.setSize(400, 400);
        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jta = new JTextArea();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);

        jtf = new JTextField();
        send = new JButton("Send");
        send.addActionListener(this);

        jp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
        jp1.add(jtf);
        jp1.add(send);

        jframe.add(jp1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jframe.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jta.append("hello client");

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addWindowListener(WindowListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addWindowListener(arg0);
        new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (ds != null)
                    try {

                        ds.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        };

    }

    public void initNetworking() {
        try {
            recieverthread = new Thread(r1);
            recieverthread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "Reciver Thread Started");
                recieveMessage(ds);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "Sender Thread Started");
                sendMessage(ds);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    public void recieveMessage(Socket rms) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "Reciver Functionality");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    rms.getInputStream()));
            String line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            jta.append("\nServer:"+line);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(Socket sms) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + "Sender Functionality");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sms.getOutputStream(), true);
        String sline = jtf.getText();
        System.out.println(sline);
        pw.println(sline);
        jtf.setText("");

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource() == send) {
            senderthread = new Thread(r2);
            senderthread.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I copied and edited from your earlier post.
The problem is that the input stream from socket is blocking. So my suggestion is to read up on async sockets in java and refactor the code below.
next to that it isn't that difficult to edit posts.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server chatServer = new Server(5555);
        System.out.println("###Start listening...###");
        chatServer.startListening();
        chatServer.acceptClientRequest();
    }

    private ServerSocket listeningSocket;
    private Socket serviceSocket;
    private int TCPListeningPort;
    private ArrayList<SocketHanding> connectedSocket;

    public Server(int TCPListeningPort) 
    {
        this.TCPListeningPort = TCPListeningPort;
        connectedSocket = new ArrayList<SocketHanding>();
    }

    public void startListening()
    {           
        try 
        {
            listeningSocket = new ServerSocket(TCPListeningPort);               
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }

    public void acceptClientRequest()
    {
        try 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serviceSocket = listeningSocket.accept();

                SocketHanding _socketHandling = new SocketHanding(serviceSocket);
                connectedSocket.add(_socketHandling);

                Thread t = new Thread(_socketHandling);
                t.start();



                System.out.println("###Client connected...### " + serviceSocket.getInetAddress().toString() );
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

class SocketHanding implements Runnable
{
    private Socket _connectedSocket;
    private PrintWriter socketOut;
    private InputStream socketIn;
    private boolean threadRunning = true;

    private String rmsg;

    public SocketHanding(Socket connectedSocket) throws IOException
    {
        _connectedSocket = connectedSocket;

        socketOut = new PrintWriter(_connectedSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        socketIn = _connectedSocket.getInputStream();
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws IOException 
    {
        threadRunning = false;
        socketIn.close();
        socketOut.close();
        _connectedSocket.close();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        socketOut.println(message);
    }

    private String receiveMessage() throws IOException 
    {   
        String t = "";

        if (_connectedSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0)
        {           
            byte[] b = new byte[8192];
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead = 0;

            if ( (bytesRead = _connectedSocket.getInputStream().read(b)) > -1 )
            {
                builder.append(new String(b, 0, b.length).trim());
            }

            t = builder.toString();
        }

        return t; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (threadRunning)
        {               
            try 
            {
                rmsg = receiveMessage();
                System.out.println(rmsg);

                if(rmsg.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                {   
                    System.out.println("###...Done###");

                    closeConnection();                                              
                    break;
                }
                else
                {   
                    String smsg = "";

                    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                    smsg = keyboard.readLine();                     
                    keyboard.close();

                    sendMessage("Server: "+smsg);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```